# Joomla webproject with large image database - performance?

Tags: php, performance, image, git, joomla

i have a webproject based on joomla with round about 6 million impressions a month and a image gallery with 360.000 images. each image of course have multiple sizes (thumb, original, resized, resized_big), why the total amount of image files is > 1 million.

today the different sizes are resizied by upload and simply stored on the server.
the database is mysql, wheres one table for the images with fields for the different paths (orignal, thumb, etc.) and other stuff.

now my question:
is this project big enough to use a cdn ? or should i only use a subdomain or something do "simulate" a cdn ? or what else can i do do improve the performance ? other db structure ? a special folder architecture ? any other ideas ?

btw: the project is versioned by git (without the images) ..

Answer (score 0):

You could optimize the storage of the images by employing the same content-addressable scheme that git uses. Ie, don't allow a separate copy for duplicates. Store images according to their hash values.